# ARN of the role that is automatically created with an Lambda function

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

In a SAM template, is there a way to reference the ARN of the role that is automatically created with an Lambda function?

I would need to use that ARN somewhere else in the template.

```
# this is the role

  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: client-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxxxxx-ApiHandlerRole-12UWXALxxxxx"
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess

# this is the lambda

  ApiHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: api-handler
      ......
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref Table
        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref Bucket
        - S3WritePolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref Bucket
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
              Resource: !GetAtt Role.Arn
```

Comment: Can you show us your example?

Comment: @petey I've pasted the relevant parts here - https://pastebin.com/dQB3k1U6

Answer (score 2):

I think what you do is separate the Resource build of the Role.

Then you can use the !Ref Role anywhere you need it, including in your lambda Role.

Comment: I might have to go this route

Answer (score 1):

---

### SOLUTION:

So, I bumped into this situation today.

Suppose your Resource Lambda is named MyLambda, then use

```
!Ref MyLambdaRole.Arn
```

Tried and tested, works like a charm.

Reason why it works: If you expand the processed template, the IAM Role resource is named using the following nomenclature

```
<lambda-logical-id>Role
```

Don't forget to upvote! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the ARN of the role yourself. It has fixed format. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-role):

> If a role isn't specified, one is created for you with a logical ID of **function-logical-idRole**.

For example using `Sub`:

```
!Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/function-logical-idRole"
```

where `function-logical-id` is your lambda function logical id.

Comment: unfortunately, that does not seem to be the case, as an additional random string seems to be added at the end: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxxxxx-ApiHandlerRole-12UWXALxxxxx

Comment: `!Sub` is beast! And normally saves the day, not today tho.

Comment: @titel If this is the case, then docs are incorrect. May need to report that to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
# this is the lambda

  ApiHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: api-handler
      Policies:
      ......

# this is the role

  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: client-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt ApiHandlerRole.Arn
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
```

Assuming that you have not specified the "**AssumeRolePolicyDocument**" for your function. 
(code above based on the pastebin), the SAM cli will generate a role called "**ApiHandlerRole**" for you.

from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-assumerolepolicydocument):

> If this property isn't specified, AWS SAM adds a default assume role
>   for this function.

Which from the looks of it you may want to just explore that property some more. I'm new to AWS SAM but there has got to be way to plug "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess" at it. :)

Hope this helps all

docs link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-assumerolepolicydocument

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is refer the ARN Attribute of the autogenerated role like

```
SomeLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
    ...other properties...
       Policies: 
    ... Some sam policies...



.... different resource reference Lambda autogenerate role...

    - Action: //some actions here
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        AWS: !GetAtt SomeLambdaFunctionRole.Arn
      Resource: "*"          

.... More template code...
```